# How to retrieve Id of the Office 365 group?

Tags: office365, microsoft-planner

I am using Graph Explorer to browse Task and Plans to retrieve list of Plans, Graph API endpoint requires the Group Id. I am unable to find the Id information while creating.

Tried to Edit the Group which I created and thought It might show the Id but it shows the Group email address in the Id column. That email address is not recognized in Graph API

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a question. As @Ingus said above, you'll need to explain what you have tried so far. You can also explain further your problem, and provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).